# Uploading images from Flex to Rails using Paperclip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache-flex, upload, paperclip

I'm looking for a way to upload images that were created in my flex app to rails. I've tried to use paperclip, but it don't seem to work.

I've got this tutorial here: http://blog.alexonrails.net/?p=218

The problem is, that they are using a FileReference to browse for files on the clients computer. They call the .upload(...) function and send the data to the upload controller. But I'm using a URLLoader to upload a image, that is modified in my Flex-App. First, here is the code from the tutorial:

```
private function selectHandler(event:Event):void {
var vars:URLVariables = new URLVariables(); 
var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest(uri); 
request.method = URLRequestMethod.POST; 
vars.description = "My Description"; 
request.data = vars;
var uploadDataFieldName:String = 'filemanager[file]'; 
fileReference.upload(request, uploadDataFieldName);
}
```

I don't know how to set that

```
var uploadDataFieldName:String = 'filemanager[file]';
```

in a URLLoader. I've got the image data compressed as a JPEG in a ByteArray. It looks like this:

```
    public function savePicture():void {
        var filename:String = "blubblub.jpg";

        var vars:URLVariables = new URLVariables();
        vars.position = layoutView.currentPicPosition;
        vars.url = filename;
        vars.user_id = 1;
        vars.comic_id = 1;
        vars.file_content_type = "image/jpeg";
        vars.file_file_name = filename;

        var rawBytes:ByteArray = new JPGEncoder(75).encode(bitmapdata);
        vars.picture = rawBytes;

        var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest(Data.SERVER_ADDR + "pictures/upload");

        request.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
        request.data = vars;

        var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader(request);
        loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, savePictureHandler);
        loader.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, errorHandlerUpload);
        loader.load(request);
    }
```

If I set the var.picture URLVariable to the bytearray, then I get the error, that the upload is nil.
Here is the Rails part:

Picture-Model:

require 'paperclip'

```
class Picture < ActiveRecord::Base

  # relations from picture
  belongs_to :comic
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :picture_bubbles
  has_many :bubbles, :through => :picture_bubbles  

  # attached file for picture upload -> with paperclip plugin
  has_attached_file :file, :path => "public/system/pictures/:basename.:extension"

end
```

and the picture controller with the upload function:

```
class PicturesController < ApplicationController

  protect_from_forgery :except => :upload

  def upload
    @picture = Picture.new(params[:picture])
    @picture.position = params[:position]
    @picture.comic_id = params[:comic_id]
    @picture.url = params[:url]
    @picture.user_id = params[:user_id]


    if @picture.save
      render(:nothing => true, :status => 200)
    else
      render(:nothing => true, :status => 500)
    end
  end
end
```

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

thx,
tux

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your "filemanager[file]" to "picture[file]".  I think that has something to do with mapping it to the controller.

Check out [RestfulX](http://wiki.github.com/dima/restfulx/restfulx-framework-and-rails-21), they have solved this problem very well.  Specifically, look at their `XMLHTTPServiceProvider#uploadFile` method.  They have in there another implementation like the one you've written.  I'm using it now in a few projects with Paperclip and it works perfectly.

I think their [Pomodo on Rails](http://github.com/dima/pomodo_on_rails/) sample app on github uses paperclip for uploading a profile image.

Hope that helps,
Lance